# Laravel-echo not joining presence-channel in production

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am using laravel-echo for handling events with pusher-js. Running it local in dev works fine but as soon as I take it live on the server and run it in prod, it's not joining the presence-channel, but still connecting to pusher.

Pushers debug console, if I open the site locally:
[image: Pusher debug console local dev]

Pushers debug consle, if I open the site in prod / live:
[image: Pusher debug console live prod]

bootstrap.js:

```js
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"]
});
```

Relevant part from my component:

```js
computed: {
    channel () {
      return window.Echo.join("jobs");
    },
    connection () {
      return window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection;
    }
  },
  created () {
    let app = this;

    app.channel
      .subscribed(user => {
        // do stuff
      })
      .joining(user => {
        // do stuff
      })
      .leaving(user => {
        // do stuff
      })
      .listen("JobsUpdated", e => {
        app.refreshData();
      })
      .on("RefreshClient", e => {
        app.refreshClient();
      });

    app.bindPusherStateChangeEvents();

    window.setInterval(function () {
      app.refreshClient();
    }, 600000);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    window.Echo.leave("jobs");
  },
```

routes/channels.php:

```php
Broadcast::channel('jobs', function ($user) {
    return $user;
});
```

config/broadcasting.php

```php
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
           ]
```

I already tried a couple of solutions from stackoverflow and laracasts such as setting encrypted to true or forcing TLS, but none worked yet. I might be missing something, but don't know what...

Comment: Are there any errors on your client when it attempts to subscribe to the private channel?
Have you ensured your authentication routes are configured and accessible from the client?

Comment: Nope, there are no errors on the client (dev console). Authentication works, because the displayed data isn't accessible without log-in.

Comment: Channels authentication is different to your app log in. Laravel will authorize channel access using the /broadcasting/auth endpoint by default. It may be worth ensuring the client is able to correctly make requests of this endpoint (your production hosting may be blocking the request). 

As a general note, if the same code is used locally and in prod but with different results it would indicate an environmental/configuration issue rather then a code issue.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up! Dev as well as prod are doing a request to `broadcasting/auth`, but on dev i receive data and in prod I do not receive anything (Response Header content-length 0). What could be the reason for it? The only difference I noticed is that I am have php7.3 on my local machine and 7.2 on the server. The connection is established after all only subscription is not...

Comment: @doydoy nvm, I've found the problem causing this issue. I forgot to check the `BROADCAST_DRIVER=` in my `.env`. It was set to `log` instead of `pusher`. Now it works. Thanks a lot, without your input I wouldn't notice it!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!